# Problems with getSavedInstanceState() and onViewStateRestored() bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I have a Fragment in an Activity and when the device is rotated, onSaveInstanceState() and onViewStateRestored() are called.

onSaveInstanceState():

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    Log.e("Fragment", "Called onSaveInstanceState");

    outState = getSavedInstanceState();

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

This is what sets the outState bundle in onSaveInstanceState():

```
public static Bundle getSavedInstanceState(){
    Bundle saveState = new Bundle();

    //Save view states
    saveState.putBoolean("startButtonVisible", buttonStart.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
    saveState.putBoolean("stopButtonVisible", buttonStop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
    saveState.putBoolean("resetButtonVisible", buttonReset.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
    saveState.putBoolean("saveButtonVisible", buttonSave.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
    saveState.putBoolean("openLatestFileButtonVisible", buttonOpenLatestFile.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

    saveState.putBoolean("editTextStartValueVisible", editTextStartValue.isEnabled());
    saveState.putBoolean("buttonStartValueDownVisible", buttonStartValueDown.isEnabled());
    saveState.putBoolean("buttonStartValueUpVisible", buttonStartValueUp.isEnabled());
    saveState.putBoolean("editTextEndValueVisible", editTextEndValue.isEnabled());
    saveState.putBoolean("buttonEndValueDownVisible", buttonEndValueDown.isEnabled());
    saveState.putBoolean("buttonEndValueUpVisible", buttonEndValueUp.isEnabled());

    return saveState;
}
```

This saves the data correctly however when onViewStateRestored() is called, the data is incorrect.

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.e("Fragment", "Called onViewStateRestored");

    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    //Restore view states
    if (savedInstanceState != null){

        restoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        if (buttonReset.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            updateUi();
        }
    }
}
```

When onViewStateRestored() is called, it also calls restoreInstanceState() which is what is supposed to restore the state of each view.

```
public static void restoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    buttonStart.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("startButtonVisible") ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    buttonStop.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("stopButtonVisible") ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    buttonReset.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("resetButtonVisible") ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    buttonSave.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("saveButtonVisible") ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    buttonOpenLatestFile.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("openLatestFileButtonVisible") ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

    editTextStartValue.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("editTextStartValueVisible"));
    buttonStartValueDown.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("buttonStartValueDownVisible"));
    buttonStartValueDown.setImageResource(buttonStartValueDown.isEnabled() ? R.drawable.ic_arrow_down : R.drawable.ic_arrow_down_gray);
    buttonStartValueUp.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("buttonStartValueUpVisible"));
    buttonStartValueUp.setImageResource(buttonStartValueUp.isEnabled() ? R.drawable.ic_arrow_up : R.drawable.ic_arrow_up_gray);
    editTextEndValue.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("editTextEndValueVisible"));
    buttonEndValueDown.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("buttonEndValueDownVisible"));
    buttonEndValueDown.setImageResource(buttonEndValueDown.isEnabled() ? R.drawable.ic_arrow_down : R.drawable.ic_arrow_down_gray);
    buttonEndValueUp.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("buttonEndValueUpVisible"));
    buttonEndValueUp.setImageResource(buttonEndValueUp.isEnabled() ? R.drawable.ic_arrow_up : R.drawable.ic_arrow_up_gray);

    Log.e("Fragment", "Restored view visibility");
}
```

Why is the data incorrect when onViewStateRestored() is called? All of the views just become invisible regardless of what the they were before. Are the bundles not the same when saving and restoring the states?

All of this code is however working when calling `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, CustomFragmentManager.savedFilesFragment).commit();` and then calling onViewStateRestored() manually.

**EDIT:** Changed field names.

**Solution:** I have replaced `outState = new Bundle(getSavedInstanceState());` with `outState.putAll(getSavedInstanceState());` and it is now working. Calling `setRetainInstance(true);` was not necessary.

Comment: what does `updateUi()` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create state bundle manually by yourself, using outState object that had passed in the method onSaveInstanceState() and restore in onCreate() method. Additional, you shoud call setRetainInstance(true) in your fragment's onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with your method signatures. Why are you using `static`? A static method cannot access instance members. This:

```
public static Bundle getSavedInstanceState()
public static void restoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Should be:

```
public Bundle getSavedInstanceState()
public void restoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Secondly, your field names are terribly un-Java-like. This:

```
BTN_startValueDown
```

Should be (for example):

```
btnStartValueDown
```

**First edit**

Should have thought of this earlier. Since you're just trying to retain the state of a fragment, simply call `setRetainInstance(true)` in your fragment's `onCreate()`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29).

**Second edit**

The other answerer is right: you shouldn't be creating another Bundle for the out-state. If you really want to create that Bundle in a separate method, use this instead:

```
outState.putAll(getSavedInstanceState());
```

Comment: I have tried making both methods non static however it seems to have no effect.